# Definition of Reference table

Tags: database

I have difficult to understand the definition of "Reference table" from the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table

Note the third paragraph:

> In the context of database design a reference table is a table into which an enumerated set of possible values of a certain field data type is divested.

Somebody provide me with a better definition or explanation?

Answer (score 17):

I have heard of these more commonly as "lookup tables", which are tables that are only used for looking up information and tend to be static (in that they do not change much or at all during the lifetime of the database).

Examples in many applications are country tables (which list country names and possibly the ISO 2 and 3 letter codes) and currency name tables.

These are tables that are used for looking up data for display purposes and normally have not other purpose (usually just an ID column and a column for the data).

Comment: Agreed, except that another common use of them is in FOREIGN KEY constraints. For example, a country-name table can be used to constrain what 2- or 3-letter codes show up in various columns throughout the DB.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used to "reference" any type of "reference data".

For example, imagine a database/table used for tracking shipments. In the "shipments" table, there's the basic info like, create date, origin location, destination location, status.

Instead of storing the full text or street address of the origin and destination locations, they can just store the ID number of a record in a different table called "locations" or "addresses".

Same deal with the "status" column. It can store the ID number of record in a different table, maybe called "ship_status". And ship_status can have a human readable name value each status number, such as 1 for "Shipment Created" and 2 for "Picked Up by Carrier" or 88 for "Shipment Lost" whatever.

This way, you can edit the name of something without having to update 1 million shipping records.